# In Golang what ensures calls to Mutex methods are not reordered relative to other statements?

Tags: go, optimization, concurrency

As I understand upon reading [Go Memory Model](https://go.dev/ref/mem) article, compiler is allowed to reorder statements, though such ability is subject to certain restrictions.

However I can't understand what restricts reordering of statements which include `Mutex` locking and unlocking, i.e.:

```
mu.RLock()
d := primes[i]
mu.RUnlock()
```

What ensures the second line is not reordered to the top? Is it about the phrase:

*Not introducing data races also means not assuming that called functions always return or are free of synchronization operations.*

i.e. simply relying on fact that `Lock()` is a function call (and I suppose, not inlined somehow) - or there is something different mechanism/logic?

Comment: I am no expert in Go, but normally locks of all sorts in all languages on all platforms involve the compiler understanding that order matters and honouring it, and indeed inserting opcodes into the generated object code to tell the CPU that order matters (to stop the CPU re-ordering too).

Comment: The answer is „The compiler if it is conforming to the specification.“

Comment: @bazza, compiler can't know that mu.Lock() for example is leading to some synchronization effort. The call could be indirect obviously.

Comment: @RodionGorkovenko I refer you to Volker's comment.

Comment: @RodionGorkovenko, and in this specific example the specification says what it means. If the compiler can re-order it as per your question, then it is not a valid Go compiler. So, really, the answer to your question is the specification, the work of the developers of the compiler, and the compiler validation tests used to establish that a compiler implementation follows the specification.

Comment: That would be an invalid optimization, so the compiler does not do that, just like moving the last return statement to the top of a function would be very effective but also an invalid optimization.

Comment: @bazza example is not from specification, thus while I understand compiler won't do such reorder, I want to figure out by which exactly rule from specification etc this is governed

Comment: @JimB sure, as I said I just want to know where is it stated and how compiler knows not to do this reordering.

Comment: @RodionGorkovenko Indeed your example is not. However, you have highlighted the correct part of the text. The compiler on seeing the call to `mu.RLock()` (or, any function call) is obliged to assume that the function call will not return and will call something like a mutex lock (or other sync statement). The net result of these assumptions is that re-ordering stops at function call boundaries. The way it's worded in that web page is a bit awkward. They could have said "do not reorder function calls with respect to other statements, otherwise there will be data races and unintended bahaviour".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements in a block are executed in source code order (ignoring the special case of the package block where dependencies control order).  Optimizations must retain the side effects of this execution order.

The specification does not specifically state that statements in a block are executed in source code order. Perhaps the authors thought it was so obvious that it does not need to be said.

If the compiler cannot prove that `i`, `primes` or the backing of `primes` is only visible to the current goroutine, then compiler cannot reorder the statements without changing the side effects of the statements.